# Getting a syntax error when using a CTE in SQL

Tags: sql

I keep getting syntax errors when trying to write CTEs in SQL. I always get the same error, and can't figure out why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated!

```sql
with myCTE as(
  SELECT
  event_id, total_session_length, first_enter_canvas, first_session_boundary
  FROM Mixpanel.events_log
  WHERE time_stamp between (first_enter_canvas AND first_session_boundary) IN
  (SELECT
  event_id,
  min(time_stamp) AS first_enter_canvas,
  min(time_stamp) + 1800 AS first_session_boundary
  FROM Mixpanel.events_log
  WHERE 
  event = 'change_screen' AND 
  screen = 'canvas'
  GROUP BY event_id
  LIMIT 10)
SELECT * FROM myCTE
```

Comment: What database are you using?  Not all databases support CTEs.  What database are you using?  Not all databases support `LIMIT`.  Plus, your `SELECT` list has a lot of columns not in the `GROUP BY`.  That is broken SQL.

Comment: At least this part has an error: `WHERE time_stamp between (first_enter_canvas AND first_session_boundary) IN
  (SELECT`

Comment: Do you know why that part is an error?

Comment: @bugsyb, This is not the correct syntax.

Comment: @bugsyb, check `between` syntax, it's `A between a1 and a2`, there is no `and` matching to `between` in your example. Then check `in` syntax, it should have a single value on left side

Comment: You are probably asking the wrong question [**What is the XY problem?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)
You are trying to fix a syntax error when you should be asking how get the data you need.  Because that inner select doesnt make sense.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to join two condition together

You probably mean

```
WHERE time_stamp between A and B
  AND time_stamp IN  ( SELECT ....)
```

Anyway for these cases the best way to find where is the error is start with a basic query and then start adding the conditions until you find where is the error.